# Modify image in runtime python

Tags: python, user-interface, opencv, opengl, runtime

I'm actually doing a program with python on a pcduino where i'm reading voltage values from an external board. My program is working fine and i can print values on console, but now i would like to show these values graphically.

An example of what i would like to do is to display a background image (a .jpg imported from a file), then depending on the value and position of a voltage array do:

- paint the left side of the image on red instead of printing 3.3V for position 1 on console
- paint the right side of the image on red instead of printing 3.3V for position 2 on console

Where the part of the background that will be painted depends on my array index, and the colour will depends on the value at this index (i.e: left for index 1, right for index 2; Red for 3.3V, Blue for 2.2V, Green for 1.1V and no modification for 0V)

```
def Setup():
    img = ImageRead('Background.jpg')
    Show(img)

def Loop():
    while(1):
        pos = pos + 1
        V[pos]=analog_read(3)*3.3/4096        #converting level to a voltage
        print "V[%d] = %f" %(pos, V[pos])     #this actually works fine
        Paintbackground(pos, V[pos])          #desired function
```

My goal is to make 'Paintbackground' something like this:

```
def Paintbackground(pos, val):
    #Zone assignement
    if   (pos==1): zone = 'left'
    elif (pos==2): zone = 'right'
    #Color assignement
    if   (val==0.0): color = 'none'
    elif (val==1.1): color = 'green'
    elif (val==2.2): color = 'blue'
    elif (val==3.3): color = 'red'
    #Modify the image and show the modification in real time
    img = ImageModify(zone, color)   #looking for this kind of instruction
    Refresh(img)                     #looking for this kind of instruction
```

I saw i can use openCV to load and modify images but i didn't see anywhere any method to upgrade/refresh in real time (without having to close the window or save then reload the file which takes a 'lot of time').

Otherwise i also saw that openGL is a library where i have a tons of tools to make graphic design, but without the possibility to load a file .jpg

Please notice that i haven't much experience programming in Python and my level is very low (even if i spended last 2 days looking tutorials and googling)

Answer (score 0):

I've created some simple example with OpenCV, showing how to modify the image in runtime. It adds a white point randomly on each refresh.

```
import cv2
import random
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((100,100))
cv2.startWindowThread()
while(1):
    cv2.imshow('',img)
    cv2.waitKey(25) # here you specify refresh rate in ms
    img[random.randint(0,99),random.randint(0,99)] = 255
```

For more info you can search OpenCV docs: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to do a rea-ltime visualization of your console output, it might be better to create and modify a plot instead of modifying images. I could think about something like the following.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep

img = plt.imread("background.png")
img_height = 500    # images height in pixel
img_width = 800    # image width

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img)


right = plt.axvspan(0, img_width//2, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
left = plt.axvspan(img_width//2, img_width, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)

colors = {0.0: None, 1.1: 'green', 2.2: 'blue', 3.3: 'red'}
zone = {1: left, 2: right}

plt.axis([0, img_width, 0, img_height])
plt.show(block=False)


def paint_background(pos, val):
    c = colors[val]
    if c is None:
        zone[pos].set_alpha(0)
    else:
        zone[pos].set_alpha(0.5)
        zone[pos].set_facecolor(c)
    plt.draw()

# Demonstrate how it looks like
example_sequence = [
    (1, 1.1), (2, 3.3), (1, 0.0), (2, 2.2),
    (1, 1.1), (2, 2.2), (2, 0.0), (2, 2.2)]

for (pos, val) in example_sequence:
    paint_background(pos, val)
    sleep(1)
```

The output will look similar to the screenshot below, with the colored regions varying as described in your question.

[image]

Using matplotlib gives you a lot of additional features like adding a title or setting axis descriptions, and if you want to, you can also write the sequence of plots to file(s).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I'm impatient to try this code but just by reading it i knew that was exactly what i was looking for. Unfortunately now i'm having troubles with my pcduino because of insufficient memory space so i can't install opencv with cv2 and numpy "modules".

But I have a new question: how can i divide my window into a matrix of rectangular zones, something like this:

    'zone = {0: center, 1: NW, 2: N, 3: NE, 4: E, 5: SE, 6: S, 7: SW, 8: W}'

Can i combine both functions axvspan and axhspan to define 9 rectangular zones in a 3x3 matrix?

Comment: Yes it is. I created a new answer to illustrate a possible solution :]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using patches to build multiple masks.

```
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches


img = plt.imread("background.png")
img_height = 500
img_width = 800

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img)

boxwidth = img_width//3
boxheight = img_height//3

zone = {}
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        p = ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle(
            (x*boxwidth, y*boxheight), boxwidth, boxheight,
            facecolor='green', alpha=0.5))
        zone[x*3 + y] = p


colors = {0.0: None, 1.1: 'green', 2.2: 'blue', 3.3: 'red'}

plt.axis([0, img_width, 0, img_height])
plt.show(block=False)


def paint_background(pos, val):
    c = colors[val]
    if c is None:
        zone[pos].set_alpha(0)
    else:
        zone[pos].set_alpha(0.5)
        zone[pos].set_facecolor(c)
    plt.draw()


example_sequence = [
    (1, 1.1), (2, 3.3), (1, 0.0), (2, 2.2),
    (5, 1.1), (2, 2.2), (8, 0.0), (2, 2.2)]

for (pos, val) in example_sequence:
    paint_background(pos, val)
    sleep(1)
```

This gives you an output like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for that answer. Finally I could try it and it worked as I expected! But now I'm having an issue with the program because when I use it with ubuntu all works fine, but now I had to move all my project on a Windows10-64bits machine and when I run the program, once the image is displayed the figure window stop responsing..

Btw I noticed that the image displayed by using this code is horizontally mirrored, how could i fix that?

Comment: I made a partition on my laptop and installed ubuntu 16.04 on it. Once I prepared the enviroment (getting python2.7 and matplotlib) I ran the code posted above and this time I'm not getting a figure window crashing but the sequence doesn't refresh patch colors nor alpha like if the instruction plt.draw() has no effect. I have been trying putting plt.show() after plt.dwar() and it refresh the image but then the program 'freezes'. I have been trying also with ipython, plt.ion() for the interactive solution and nothing changes. Any idea?

Comment: Finnally I could solve the problem (spending a lot of time but it works!)
I checked which version of matplotlib I had on both devices, it seems like my computer installed the updated version 1.5.1 meanwhile pc-duino installed an out to date version: 1.1.1rc2... Once i had downgrade matplotlib on pc an other issue comes: on plt.show no one figure appears. Then after some researches i found that the reason of this is due to backend, had to switch from agg to tkagg and now it works fine. THANKS!